# Problem running an app on the iPhone with Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

Hello I am having some problems running my app on my iPhone when I run the app from me this error:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/indumonta/AndroidStudioProjects/contagem_de_pessoas/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Tigomes.
```

### Terminal:

```
MBP-de-Luis:~ indumonta$ plutil Info.plist
Info.plist: file does not exist or is not readable or is not a regular file (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=Info.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd621d04140 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}})
```

[image: terminal - plutil Info.plist]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

Open your project directory and run from within

> flutter create contagem_de_pessoas

This should create the missing info.plist

Comment: I tried to do that but it still gives me the same error, have any more suggestions.
Thank you!